# ReSharper [PublicAPI] not applying to members

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-analysis

I'm using ReSharper 2017.2 in VS 2017 and am using the [PublicAPI](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#PublicAPIAttribute) attribute so ReSharper doesn't trigger warnings about public members that aren't used.

In previous versions marking the class level used to suppress all "not used" warnings for that classes members.  But that seems to have changed?  **Is there a setting or other way to tell ReSharper - if a class is marked [PublicAPI] treat all of that classes members as being part of that PublicAPI?**

For example, I have a class:

```
public class PublicApiMessage
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

But this triggers [Member can be made private](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/MemberCanBePrivate.Local.html), [Auto-property accessor is never used](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AutoPropertyCanBeMadeGetOnly.Global.html), and other ReSharper suggestions/warnings.

I would expect marking the class `[PublicAPI]` to hide these warnings:

```
[PublicAPI]
public class PublicApiMessage
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not.  I have to annontate *every* member in a public api class???

```
[PublicAPI]
public class PublicApiMessage
{
    [PublicAPI] // this shouldn't be necessary to suppress warnings on Description
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. First, this class does not trigger any warnings for me, and second - if I change it to produce some warning - adding PublicAPI on class level removes that warning. How do you trigger that warning with provided code?

Comment: @Evk - are you using ReSharper?

Comment: Well, sure  I do :)